# How to autogenerate insert timestamp with millisecond precision in UTC format in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, insertTimestamp <- )
```

For the following column `insertTimestamp` I want to generate timestamp in this format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS` and it should be in UTC time zone.

How do I do it? What is the most efficient way of doing this?

**Most importantly** - If my server has incorrect time, will it mess up my database time?

Comment: SQLite always uses the system notion of time for where it is running. It has no way to check if that's wrong or not; that would be a vast pile of complexity that's outside the scope of being a database engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the function [`strftime()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) function with `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f'` format and the `'now'` modifier which will return the current datetime with milliseconds in UTC:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  insertTimestamp TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT(strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', 'now')) 
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/8E0qDrOa).

[SQLite is serverless](https://www.sqlite.org/serverless.html), so it will return the current datetime from your system and not any server.

Comment: I have a follow up question, how do I ensure that my local system has the correct time so my db does not have incorrect date? Are there any industry standard practices? Do I need to enable 'set time automatically' setting that is available in operating systems?

Comment: @forpas Thanks for mentioning strftime. Isn't the calculation of UTC missing in your answer? How to achieve that?

Comment: @Vishal (1)This depends on the operating system, admin/user rights and security of the system. There is no standard practice applicable to all (2) strftime() with 'now' returns the UTC time. There is no need for anything else.

Comment: @forpas Yes, you are right, I've tried it out. Strange that the [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) doesn't mention this.

Comment: @Stringeater it is mentioned in *3. Modifiers*. Search for "Universal Coordinated Time (UTC) is used."

Comment: @forpas How do I ensure that time is always accurate on Ubuntu running Node-SQLite?

Comment: @Vishal the accuracy of your system's time has nothing to do with Node or SQLite. You can ask this question in https://askubuntu.com

Comment: @forpas  is there a way to check the byte size of this string 'strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', 'now''

Comment: @Vishal `strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', 'now')` returns a string which is always 23 characters long which means that its size is 23 bytes since the string does not contain multi-byte characters.